# Trying to convert date to using .ToShortTimeString to get the time only in my web Api - Not working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the time only from a datetime variable but i'm having a few difficulties .
I have a model like this :

```
public class table{    
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string username {get; set;}
    public DateTime DatePosted {get;set;}    
}
```

then i have a method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public  IHttpActionResult GetPostedTime(){
    var gettime = 
        context.table.where(x => x.username == "some user")
                     .select(x => 
                        new {
                            x.Id,
                            x.username,
                            x.DatePosted.ToshortTimeString() // try to get the time only here but getting        //error -  ​*anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name*​
                        });
    return gettime;
}
```

Is there any easier way i could get the time only from my datetime variable or how could i fix the error and get the time only.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the names

```
var gettime = context.table.where(x => x.username == "some user").select(x => new {
  Id = x.Id,
  username = x.username,
  DatePosted = x.DatePosted.ToshortTimeString() 
});
```

Comment: Only true for `DatePosted`, though. `Id` and `username` could still be inferred. But perhaps you were just being consistent. I don't mind that.